# Failed to create a new object in app-engine: repeated primary key (id: type long)

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

1.- Create object id

```
// Allocate a key for the conference -- let App Engine allocate the ID
final Key<Conference> conferenceKey = factory().allocateId(profileKey, Conference.class);
// Get the Conference Id from the Key
final long conferenceId = conferenceKey.getId();
```

2.- Create objeto, add id

```
// Create Conference
Conference conference = new Conference(conferenceId,userId,conferenceForm);
```

3.- Save object:

```
// Save Conference and Profile Entities
ofy().save().entities(profile,conference).now();
ofy().save().entity(conference).now();
```

4.- Error, multiples times using same id (Datastore google)

[image: datastore google platform]

> Note: Same objects created with same ANDROID_CLIENT_ID (release mode)

Comment: What you are seeing is correct as the two entities with ID=1 have different Parents, so they have different Keys.  It's the full key path that is unique - the Name/ID is unique only within its Parent scope.

Comment: @tx802 - Please, post this comment as an answer. It's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct.  Your screenshot shows 2 entities with ID=1, but with different Parents (ancestor paths).

A Datastore Key is formed from its full ancestor path and it is the Key that is unique - not the ID/Name.  The ID/Name is only unique within the scope of its Parent.  If an entity has no ancestor, then you would expect the ID to be unique.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Ancestor_paths) gives a good overview of Keys.